# MMDrawerController instantiation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use the MMDrawerController in my app. I've downloaded the source and the dependencies. This is the code that I've added to the AppDelegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIViewController * leftDrawer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController * center = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
    UIViewController * rightDrawer = [[UIViewController alloc] init];

    MMDrawerController * drawerController = [[MMDrawerController alloc]
                                             initWithCenterViewController:center
                                             leftDrawerViewController:leftDrawer
                                             rightDrawerViewController:rightDrawer];

    UINavigationController * navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:center];

    [navigationController setRestorationIdentifier:@"MMExampleCenterNavigationControllerRestorationKey"];

    [self.drawerController setRestorationIdentifier:@"MMDrawer"];
    [self.drawerController setMaximumRightDrawerWidth:200.0];
    [self.drawerController setOpenDrawerGestureModeMask:MMOpenDrawerGestureModeAll];
    [self.drawerController setCloseDrawerGestureModeMask:MMCloseDrawerGestureModeAll];



    [self.drawerController
     setDrawerVisualStateBlock:^(MMDrawerController *drawerController, MMDrawerSide drawerSide, CGFloat percentVisible) {
         UIViewController * sideDrawerViewController;
         if(drawerSide == MMDrawerSideLeft){
             sideDrawerViewController = drawerController.leftDrawerViewController;
         }
         else if(drawerSide == MMDrawerSideRight){
             sideDrawerViewController = drawerController.rightDrawerViewController;
         }
         [sideDrawerViewController.view setAlpha:percentVisible];
     }];

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    [self.window setRootViewController:self.drawerController];

    return YES;
}
```

However the app runs to a blank screen.What am I missing?

Comment: Do you using cocoapods ?

Comment: No I'm manually adding the dependencies. Please see edit.

Answer (score 4):

```
UINavigationController * navigationController = 
 [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:drawerController];   

[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

and  no need to write below line:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
```

Hope this will perfectly work.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line of code before return with the following

```
[self.window setRootViewController:navigationController];
```

Comment: Nope didn't work. Also I have no xib or storyboard, assuming that everything is being generated programmatically. Do I need one?

Comment: Yes you try to add an xib(or storyboard) with blank view otherwise you cant add controls dynamically to the viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are setting the center, right and left `views` with `UIViewController` and also these `UIViewControllers` settings are not defined
in order to integrate the `MMDrawerController` right do the following.

1. In order to gurantee having views initialized you can use this code to get the `UIViewControllers` created in your storyboard

   ```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard;

   storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:"Story board name" bundle:nil];

   UIViewController * leftSideNavController = 
   [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
                                                   "Left side view identifier"];

   UIViewController * centerSideNavController = 
   [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
                                                      "center view identifier"];

   UIViewController * rightSideNavController = 
   [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:
                                                  "right side view identifier"];
   ```
2. then using the `UIViewControllers` you got from the previous point initialize the MMDrawerController

   ```
   self.drawerController = 
     [[MMDrawerController alloc] 
            initWithCenterViewController:centerSideNavController 
                leftDrawerViewController:leftSideNavController 
               rightDrawerViewController:rightSideNavController];
   ```